# Injecting Javascript into UISlider

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, string, uislider

I have been battling a problem now for about a week and it's really annoying me. I have embedded html into a uiwebview in Xcode and i want to launch the my javascript function of

ZoomChanger(Enter Value Here)

based on the value of UIslider. I tried this code...

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ZoomChanger(100,200,300);", slider.value];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:string];
```

but it only zooms in once and doesn't continue zooming and won't unzoom when uislider is brought back to the beginning. It works fine on android but I can't get it to work on iOS.

Comment: if you show the code you use to initialize the slider it'd be easier (unless you use IB then show the values you use for it's properties).
otherwise it's pretty difficult to understand what you are struggling to do, Krizz's response seemed sufficient to me otherwise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending `ZoomChanger(100,200,300);` each time. 
I believe you want to send a value from the slider.
What is `ZoomChanger`? I assume it is a javascript function `function ZoomChanger(x)`....

You will need something like:

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ZoomChanger(%d);", slider.value * 10]; 
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:string];
```

See this [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html).

Comment: It didn't work, i read the documentation and i still didn't get it. Basically I want the slider to have a min of zero and a max of 8. And at value one i want it to launch ZoomChanger(10 (for example)) and little by little all the way to 8. and if the slider goes back down a value so does the zoom. Thanks for the speedy response btw. Oh and zoom changer is just to zoom my embedded html in my webview.

Comment: So what is the value to be passed for 8? 80? If so, you can observe it is `slider.value * 10`.

Comment: Yes, but i want the zoom to increase as i slide to the right, and decrease as i slide to the left, AHH! i hate code lol.

Comment: Whats going to work? I tried the suggestion of slider.value *10?

Comment: If it doesn't, it's probably a problem with your javascript function.

Comment: `sliderChanged` IB action of `UISlider`.